# Word for neologisms derived from the names of fictional characters

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology, neologisms

Is there a word that refers to or describes the subset of neologisms derived specifically from the names of fictional characters?

Comment: I don't think there is a word quite *that* specific. However I may speak too soon, EL&U has a wealth of specific knowledge…

Comment: @BladorthinTheGrey Perhaps a commonly used qualifier? Something along the lines of:  "Type" Neologism

Comment: Maybe we have to macgyver a word to fit your needs ;)

Answer (score 5):

If you can handle two words: we might describe such terms as *literary eponyms*.

From [Daily Writing Tips](http://www.dailywritingtips.com/5-types-of-eponyms/):

> **3. Literary Eponyms**
>
> Fictional characters often evoke such strong qualities that we assign their names to those qualities: faustian, quixotic. We also refer to people who exhibit qualities of literary characters by directly associating them, such as when we call someone a Casanova, a Romeo, or a Svengali (retaining initial capitalization), but some other such terms, such as lothario, are lowercased.

Comment: This works for me. Do you know by any chance the reasoning for retaining capitalization in certain cases? 

I see the Merriam-Webster dictionary gives "lothario" with a lowercase L, but states that it is often capitalized. The New Oxford American Dictionary gives it capitalized with no notice.

Comment: I would think that when the lexicographer determines that the term's meaning no longer derives from its namesake in the public consciousness - when it evokes the quality but not the character - that they may decide it no longer needs to be treated like a proper name.

Comment: Wikipedia has some more information and examples: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eponym#Orthographic_conventions